# Postpone retrofit retry

Tags: android, callback, retrofit2

I have the following scenario in my app:

1. I make an http request (Rq) to an endpoint that requires a valid token; I end up having a 401 error;
2. As advised on various S.O questions, I implemented a token refresh with the Authenticator class.
3. Thing is in our backend, there's no endpoint (so far) for refreshing the endpoint, this "fresh" token is only provided after the user logs in again.
4. So, once I detect a 401 error, I retrieve the login infos stored locally (say in my Shared preferences), make a request to the endpoint for login
5. If the request is successful I get a new token and proceed normally with the request (Rq) that failed.
6. But if the login fails after some time (say because the data read from SP were incorrect for example...), the idea is to display the login UI to the user. The user fills the login form and makes and attempts to login again.
7. If the login is successful I'd like to resume the request (Rq) that failed.
   What is the best approach possible ?

**NB:** We've got Callbacks all around the place...so no RxJava nor Kotlin right now :)

Answer (score 0):

use Rx2 and Retrofit combination then you will achieve it easily, it will look something like :

```
service.login(username, password)
            .retry(RETRY_FETCH_COUNT)
            .onErrorResumeNext {
                return@onErrorResumeNext doSomethingElse()
            }
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .subscribe({ loginResponse ->
               handleLogin(loginResponse)
            }, {
                onLoginError()
            })
```

Comment: Thanks Antonis...but right now, we have callbacks all around the place i.e no RxJava2/RxAndroid2, Kotlin.

Comment: My advice would be use these libraries as soon as possible, you wont regret it :) Please post some code that you have now

Comment: I was thinking of using something like a Stack (or Queue) to store failed requests and later retrieve them when need be

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the code, but it could be many approaches to achieve it. Of course cleanest one is Rx and Retrofit. But also you can somehow request states, or create Request model and make a list of them so you would be able to see states. Like I said there is many approaches